# Angular material mat sidenav items

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have implemented sidenav items using mat list items but when i attach routerLink to it i get a blue outline on click. I want to know if mat list items are only used in mat sidenav for links or any other components because I’m not even getting ripple effects on click

Link: http://ng.devlops.io
[image: angular app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mat-list is fine inside mat-sidenav.

In order to get rid of the blue border add the following to your **app's global style**

```css
mat-list-item {
  outline: unset;
}
```

In order to add ripple you should add matRipple to mat-list-item like this:

```html
<mat-list-item ... matRipple>
  Home
</mat-list-item>
```

If it does not work you will need to upload your code

Comment: Thanks ill try this

Comment: The css worked now ill add ripple and build again

Comment: Also can you see why the window is scrolling down after clicking on menu button on toolbar?

Comment: I can't see this behavior but try changing the height of mat-sidenav-container from 100% to `height: calc(100vh - 64px);`
vh is percentage of the viewport height and 64px is the height of your toolbar

Comment: Also i have a question.. should i import material components in the component I’m using or globally in app.module?

Comment: You have to import to some module you cant just import to the conponent. Which module depends on where you use it